# Como exibir a requisição http de um browser, e a resposta http do servidor

Tags: php, java, http, navegador-de-internet, http-request

Gostaria de obter esta informação para estudar exemplos completos de protocolos https com Cookie e Sessions, seja por meio de Socket Java, PHP. Se possível por meio do próprio browser.

Comment: No Firefox tem um complemento [Tamper data](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/tamper-data/?src=search) onde é possível ver e controlar todas as requisições, inclusive modificando os headers, e os dados post.

Answer (score 5):

Cara vc consegue fazer isso de forma simples!
Todos os browsers modernos tem essa funcionalidade "de frabrica" :)

Por exemplo: Se vc usa o browser Google Chrome basta pressionar a tecla F12 depois clicar na aba Network e pronto!!! Vc tem todas as requisições HTTP enviadas e recebidas.

Answer (score 3):

Achei estas Extensões para o Chrome

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-spy/agnoocojkneiphkobpcfoaenhpjnmifb
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo